# Google scholar citation count,

Tags: research-process, citations

There's a researcher whose work I'm studying, and I was curious and looked him up; Google Scholar says that he has 16,000 ish citations.  But when I scroll through his publications on Google Scholar, some of his top papers have a couple hundred citations only.  That can't possibly add up to 16,000.  So, how is that total number actually derived?

Comment: Google scholar only shows the first 20 (highly cited papers), if you go all the way down and clink on "show more", you will see the complete list of publications and citations.

Comment: Some authors use automatic inclusion of papers. Especially with Chinese names this can lead to papers that belong to lots of different authors grouped together in the same (wrong) profile. You can spot these cases when your guy seems to be an expert on evolutionary biology and social sciences and high energy physics and...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about academia as defined in the help center, but about the technical workings of a piece of software (Google Scholar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Scholar sometimes counts different papers with similar names into the same publication (marked with an asterisk*) -- these usually add up the citations from multiple papers, which might or might not even belong to the same author. Some scholars also just rack up a lot of citations from spreading themselves out with quantity. It's just as possible that he's published a *lot* of papers with hundreds of citations.